# Are probability measures induced by random variables always regular?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $(\mathbb{R}^k, \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^k), P)$ be the probability space induced by the $k\times 1$ vector valued random variable $X$, with $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ the completion of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$.

Is it true that $P$ is regular, that is, for any measurable set $A$,

(1) $P(A) = \sup \{ P (C) \mid C \subseteq A, C \text{ compact and measurable} \}$

and

(2) $P(A) = \inf \{ P (C) \mid A \subseteq C, C \text{ open and measurable} \}$

Because $X$ is a random variable, it is bounded in probability, so I can prove that (1) works for $C$ bounded but not necessary closed.

However, I have no idea how to prove that $C$ can be closed in (1) or open in (2).

Comment: Is this true for $\mathbb R^{1}$ ? I have a feeling it's a simple application of some real analysis/measure theory property or trick and $$P(A) = E[1_A] = \int_A d\mathbb P = \int_{\Omega} 1_A d\mathbb P$$ Would this then be the [measure-theoretic *interpretation* of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_interpretations) ?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "measurable" here?  Measurable for the probability measure $P$?  Or Borel?

Comment: Measurable for $P$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Every finite Borel measure on a metric space is regular. Since $P$ is a Borel probability measure and $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a metric space, $P$ is regular.

More details here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22174/regular-borel-measures-on-metric-spaces

Comment: Kechris' book (descriptive set theory) also has a proof of this.